# Como alertar sobre o comportamento de um moderador?

Tags: debate, sinalização, moderadores

A função de moderador é um posto importante no site, mas as vezes um moderador poderia agir de forma deliberada e refestelar-se com seus poderes e deixar as pessoas principalmente os iniciantes sem ter como se defender.

É possível sinalizar para os outros moderadores?

Comment: Apenas uma duvida, você esta falando de moderador com `♦` ou de um usuario com privilégios expandidos? Sua frase *pessoas principalmente os iniciantes sem ter como se defender* soa como sendo alguma postagem fechada ou negativada. Note que fechar uma pergunta nao significa "deletar permanentemente", você pode tentar reabri-la. O problema e que voce tem que entender como a comunidade funciona. Realmente ninguem gosta de levar negativos, mas você tem que ver se realmente e algo arbitrário e acredito que não seja. O grande e querer entender como funciona a comunidade. Nao me leve a mal ...

Comment: ... estou tentando apenas lhe orientar amigo.

Comment: Muito bem, obrigado!! Não eu tive problemas com perguntas fechadas!! Mas eu recebi um certo comentário de um certo moderador que denegria não a mim mas outros usuários que possivelmente não souberam se expressar devido ao nervosismo  tem suas indagações desprezadas e regadas ao relento...

Comment: Pena entendo o que quis dizer, mas as vezes parece denegrir, mas devemos manter a mente aberta, outra coisa as vezes nao era um comentario de um moderador, mas sim de um usuario com privilegios extendidos. Mas entendo que fique chateado. Acho que a acao talvez seja o flag mesmo. Seja bem vindo!

Comment: Não se preocupe!! Obrigado  pela atenção @Guilherme Nascimento.

Comment: Muitas vezes por falta de um smiley :) , vi que meus comentários terminaram soando secos/agressivos/rudes... Mas, bom, *this is real life*, e tem muita gente que confunde um ataque ao problema como um ataque pessoal. Os chefes, diretores e executivos pelo mundo de trabalho afora podem ser bem mais rudes, pode contar com isso. (smiley) jejejej

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As sinalizações são analisadas pelos moderadores, portanto se você possui uma reclamação sobre a moderação e não esteja confortável em tratar o assunto diretamente conosco pode preencher o formulário de [Entre em contato conosco](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/contact) onde quem tem acesso a esse canal de comunicação é única e exclusivamente a equipe de funcionários do Stack Exchange.

Se sua necessidade não exige tanto sigilo assim, pode simplesmente sinalizar o que está te incomodando para que a própria moderação tente entender e resolver o caso. Acredito que isso resolva na maioria dos casos.

Comment: Muito bem! Obrigado pela vital informação!! Math!

Comment: De nada :)​​​​​

Comment: E, é claro, pode sempre discutir o assunto aqui no meta ou mesmo no chat, se você se sentir confortável em expor o caso publicamente. Dito isso, eu considero nossa equipe de moderadores bem... moderada :) É bastante receptiva a críticas também @pena

Comment: Que legal, isso é que é bacana!! Quem sabe no futuro eu venha a me tornar um moderador também  @bfavaretto!!